Spring Boot native image - how to remote debug?
I cannot find a way to remote debug via Intellij a Spring Boot native image generated with spring-boot-maven-plugin and running inside Kubernetes.
I could not find any info on Spring Boot native image support page:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/native-image/index.html
I'm using the -g build option, that should take care about adding debug information to the executable:
https://www.graalvm.org/22.3/reference-manual/native-image/guides/debug-native-image-process/
And I'm adding the following jvm args to the spring-boot-maven-plugin:
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

But when I try to attach the debugger to the remove JVM, I get:
k port-forward my-service-65fb694c9b-swzqz 5005
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5005 -> 5005
Forwarding from [::1]:5005 -> 5005
Handling connection for 5005
E0612 11:25:35.287370  675301 portforward.go:413] an error occurred forwarding 5005 -> 5005: error forwarding port 5005 to pod 5e8effc4007042dadd57666ae576b3649edc116ec0192e5c34b371a45a5e5832, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-eab6b185-a501-d62e-b4a5-a4b3065153cb": failed to connect to localhost:5005 inside namespace "5e8effc4007042dadd57666ae576b3649edc116ec0192e5c34b371a45a5e5832", IPv4: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:5005: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6: address localhost: no suitable address found 

Note that port-forwarding 8080 works fine instead.
Here is my POM setup:
    [...]
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    [...]

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>

                    <image>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>-J-Xmx8g --parallelism=2 -g</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>
                        </env>

                        <publish>true</publish>
                        <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>${docker.repository.external.url}/repository/docker/${project.name}:${project.version}
                            </tag>
                        </tags>
                        <name>${docker.repository.external.url}/repository/docker/${project.name}</name>
                    </image>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

Any idea? Thanks!
UPDATE:
Just few additional info:
This video from 2 weeks ago shows how to do such spring native remote debug with command line debugger, but quite "complicated" and time consuming for daily business in my opinion:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfE5nh-QdNc
Actually modern IDEs should be able to use linux debugger in the background and translate everything in order to let you debug in the UI like you were used with regular java applications, that video shows a small example with Eclipse IDE in the very last minutes. But I didn't find any example about doing it with Intellj, there's a plug-in but not documented anywhere or I didn't find anything:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19237-graalvm-native-debugger
Here instead, you can see a nice example how to do such native remote debugging against a Quarkus application:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhTR_ECSaAo
This is exactly what I was looking for, but for Spring Boot native.

You need to use gdb. Reread the debug article.

This is not answering about how to handle it via Intellij idea

IntelliJ knows how to debug native programs with gdb.

Thorbjørn, easy to say that it is possible. Can you explain how? I googled a lot but didn't find any guide, tutorial or even examples.
Again, my question is: how can I remote debug from intellij a spring boot native image application running on a kubernetes POD ?

Do you have an ultimate license?

Yes I do have latest intellij ultimate

After you have converted your sources into a native program it is no longer running in a JVM so the Java debugger will not work.
You need to use gdb and support for that has been moved into the CLion flavor of IntelliJ.
It looks like this describes what you want to do: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-debug-via-gdb-gdbserver.html
That said, this is only for very experienced Java programmers.  You may want to consider deploying it as a normal, non-native Java program until you have reached production quality.

This is partially true. Modern IDEs should be able to use linux debugger in the background and translate everything in order to let you debug in the UI like you were used with regular java applications (you need to add -g arg while building the native image in order to have debug info in the binary, and optionally -O0 to avoid optimizations). For example this video shows what I said for debugging native Quarkus applications: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhTR_ECSaAo but I didn't find any doc to do exactly that with Spring Boot native ones.
